# Add whitespace to CSV number in PHP

Tags: php, csv, whitespace, fputcsv

I have a system that takes an Excel file, does some manipulation and then exports to a CSV file ready for import into something else.

Everything works except the numbers; when the CSV file is import into the final system the numbers show up as 1E+11 for example.

I have a previous CSV file that works and the only difference I can see when I open it in Notepad is that there is a whitespace after the number e.g

```
123456643567 ,872871643567 ,465435654356
```

Whereas the new file doesn't have any whitespace after the number e.g

```
123456643567,872871643567,465435654356
```

This is the only difference I can see so can only presume this is causing the problem, however I don't know how to add that white space in. If I try and just append a whitespace to the end then the numbers are surrounded by speech marks and this still doesn't work e.g

```
"123456643567 ","872871643567 ","465435654356 "
```

Is there a way to add this in or is there something else at work causing this issue?

**Edit:**

For reference, below is the code I have to read in the Excel file using PHPExcel:

```
// Identify the type of $file
$file_type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($file);
// Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($file_type);
// Load $file to a PHPExcel Object
$obj = $reader->load($file);
// Load file into rowIterator
$rows = $obj->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();
// Create array
$excel_array = array();
foreach($rows as $row){
    $cells = $row->getCellIterator();
    $index = $row->getRowIndex ();
    // Check row contains data
    if($index>=$req_array[$req][0]){
        foreach ($cells as $cell) {
            $column = $cell->getColumn();
            // Check column is needed
            if(strpos($req_array[$req][1],'|'.$column.'|')!==false){
                $excel_array[$index][$column] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            }
        }
    }
}
// Return array
return $excel_array;
```

The req_array just includes a string of required columns and the row to start on.

Comment: Are you importing those columns as Text? If so, they shouldn't show up in scientific notation.

Comment: Maybe it's rather the size of the numbers? The system is switching to scientific notation for very large numbers...?! Or maybe the system is not really expecting CSV, but fixed-width columns?

Comment: I'm using PHPExcel to read the original Excel file, I will add the code to my question.

Comment: @deceze - I did think that but the old CSV file works fine and the numbers are exactly the same length. Like I say the only difference between the old and new file is that whitespace after the number.

Comment: Its likely just the column width that needs to be adjusted to show the full number.  You can set your output with in PHPExcel...$cell->getColumnDimension("A")->setAutoSize(true);

Comment: @KyleK - The full number is in the CSV file, it seems to have read the number fine but for some reason they have different effects when importing into the next system (which isn't my system so I have no control over the code of that)

Comment: Then it might have to formatted as a string when exporting with PHPExcel.  setCellValueExplicit('A1', '0029', PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);

Comment: I will give that a go. I will need to rewrite some of the code as it doesn't export using PHPExcel, only imports. It exports using fputcsv.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like the number with space is being handled as a string, because, well, numbers don't support spaces. Without the space the system is happy to cast it to a number. And it applies scientific notation formatting to numbers under certain circumstances. That's not terrifically uncommon for systems to do, it depends on the programmer to control that behaviour. So, sounds like the "space hack" was a way to force the system to treat the number as a string, which suppresses any special formatting it may apply. The system really should be fixed, not the CSV.

Comment: @deceze - That seems odd though, if the system is treating the number with the space as a string and it works fine, why then if I add a space and force it to a string does that not work? I think speaking to the developers of the other system is going to be my only option here, find out exactly what it is doing with the files when they are import.